# Nothing selected when creating data-bound check boxes with Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a list of check boxes with Knockout.js.  The list itself comes from a data-bound source, as well as which items in the list are selected.  The model I have looks something like this:

```
var ViewModel = function ()
{
   this.areas = [{AreaId: 1, Name: 'Test 1'}, {AreaId: 2, Name: 'Test 2'}, {AreaId: 3, Name: 'Test 3'}];
   this.AreasImpacted = ko.observableArray([1, 2]);
};
```

Now, I want to create a list of check boxes with the labels *Test 1*, *Test 2*, and *Test 3*.  I want to have *Test 1* and *Test 2* checked.  My HTML looks like so:

```
<span class="areas" data-bind="foreach: areas">
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: AreaId, checked: $parent.AreasImpacted" /><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></label>
</span>
```

This *does* draw each check box with the proper name, and I can verify the `value` attribute of each checkbox is being set correctly, however nothing gets checked!  I've also tried setting `this.AreasImpacted` to just `2`.  When I do that, all 3 checkboxes are checked!

Totally confused!

**Update:**

If I change the model to:

```
this.AreasImpacted = ko.observableArray(['1', '2']);
```

Then things work as expected.

If I had to guess, I'd say the `for-each` binding is translating each value to a string.  I'm curious if this is by-design, or a Knockout.js bug.  I would expect the input's value to be numeric, as that's what I bound it to.

**Bug Filed:**

Since the above code does not work as [documented](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html), I've filed a [bug](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/838) on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change things up a bit, to check if the `AreaId` of the area you're rendering is contained in the `AreasImpacted` array:

```
data-bind="value: AreaId, checked: $parent.AreasImpacted.indexOf(AreaId) >= 0"
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroenheijmans/hEd2k/) for a working demo.

**NOTE:** Using this technique, checking or unchecking one of the bound check boxes will *not* update the data source.

Alternatively, you can make the array a list of strings, like such:

```
this.AreasImpacted = ko.observableArray(['1', '2']);
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroenheijmans/TXhtA/) for a demo.

---

As noted in the comments, the [KnockoutJS documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) seems to suggest that the OP's original syntax should work. You can even get that to work by making the items in the array into strings ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroenheijmans/TXhtA/)).

The KnockoutJS source can tell us why this happens. Look at the [`checked.js` default binding](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/checked.js) to see the relevant bit of code that will decide whether to check an input or not:

```
element.checked = ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(value, element.value) >= 0;
```

In this context:

- `value` is the array of area id's (numbers, in the OP's original code)
- `element` is the `<input .../>` checkbox HtmlElement

As such, the `element.value` will always be of type string, which is why the checkbox will only be checked if the items in the array are also strings.

Whether this is a *bug* in KnockoutJS, or just some unexpected but logical behavior: I'm not sure.

Comment: From the [Knockout Docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html): *Special consideration is given if your parameter resolves to an array. In this case, KO will set the element to be checked if the value matches an item in the array, and unchecked if it is not contained in the array.* - Meaning, since `AreasImpacted` is an array, it should be checked if the item exists in the array.  Why does it not work as documented?

Comment: Mmmhh, you're right. Don't ask me "why" (yet), but [it makes a difference if you use strings in the array](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroenheijmans/TXhtA/) :O

Comment: @MikeChristensen updated my answer, if I'm not mistaken I've found out why KnockoutJS does this.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks for tracking it down to the source code level.  I think I have enough knowledge to build a work around.

Comment: Looks like casting the data source to a string is also the only way to go if you want two-way data binding :)